# Python 2.7. Need help to work out mixing words in a list (first python project)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I'm working on my first python project. Its (yet another) password dictionary generator based on inputting likeky password information about the target (in this case social engineering myself!).

I've got the menu based part of it working fine, it enables the user to add words of their choice and choose options for output filename, adding numbers and adding special characters.

What I need it to do is:-

1) input words into a list (eg kidsname, birthmonth, starsign) Done this bit successfully. its in [listA]

2) Capitalise the first letter of each word (eg kidsname -> Kidsname) Done this bit successfully. Its then saved in a [listB].

3) take the words in [listA] and [listB] and jumble them in to all possible combinations (eg. kidsname, kidsnamebirthmonth, Starsignkidsname, BirthmonthstarsignKidsname etc etc.... This is the part I'm currently stumped with. i've tried itertools.permutations with no joy.

eventually.....
4) add number sequences to the start and end (eg. 123kidsnameBirthmonth, starsignKidsname666 etc...)

5) add special characters (eg. Starsignbirthmonth123 -> St@rsignbirthm0nth123)

Any ideas. Help appreciated. I just want advice on step 3 at the moment. I'll cross step 4 and 5 when I get to them!
Thanks
G.R.

Comment: Show us what you've got.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: for L in range(0, len(tempmixlist)+1):
        for L in itertools.permutations(tempmixlist, L):
            print (tempmixlist)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to provide questions that can be answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For step 3:  How about:

```
def eachCombination(listA, listB):
  for a in listA:
    for b in listB:
      yield a + b
      yield b + a

for combination in eachCombination(
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['blue', 'green', 'red']):
  print combination
```

This should print this list:

```
oneblue
blueone
onegreen
greenone
onered
redone
twoblue
bluetwo
twogreen
greentwo
twored
redtwo
threeblue
bluethree
threegreen
greenthree
threered
redthree
```

A more general approach can make use of `itertools` like this:

```
for product in itertools.product(
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
    ['cancer', 'leo', 'virgo']):
  for combination in itertools.permutations(product):
    print ''.join(combination)
```

Try this ;-)

If you want to combine this with varying capitalization for each element, try this:

```
for product in itertools.product(
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
    ['cancer', 'leo', 'virgo']):
  for combination in itertools.permutations(product):
    originalAndCapitalized = [ (original, original.capitalize())
        for original in combination ]
    for words in itertools.product(*originalAndCapitalized):
      print ''.join(words)
```

One thing I want to stress here is that you should **not** create lists.  Using lists in such a context will fill up your memory in no time.  The number of combinations created with a small number of variations can become huge.  You only need to *generate* them and iterate over them.

See to it that you know about the `yield` keyword in this context.

Comment: You are so right.  I had a list comprehension first and changed that in the last step.  I will clarify the whole code.  Done (feel free to remove your comment in case you find it obsolete now).

Comment: Thanks for replying! Alfe, You are almost there with what I am after but what I want is slightly different. So... ListC=listA+listB, I want combinations then for listC so for example listA=['word1', 'word2', 'word3',] listB has (difference being the capitalisation) ['Word1','Word2','Word3'] so listC=['word1', 'word2','word3','Word1','Word2','Word3'] and from this list I'd like to make the combinations. Obviously theres no point having 'word1' and 'Word1' as a combination so I'd like to avoid that but all other combinations of 2 and 3 words is what I am after. Thanks!!!

Comment: Generating possible passwords for cracking one is a fine art, not a straight-forward science.  I don't know what your concrete ideas and wishes are, so I cannot adjust my code accordingly.  If you manage to formulate them precisely, you probably have already written the code yourself because the trick often lies in formulating them precisely enough.

Comment: I added a version which also writes out all capitalization variants.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to give both a go tonight. I think the problem may not just be this issue but because this is my first go at python my coding is probably a bit clunky. Again, many thanks

Comment: Alfe, Thanks so much. Just tried those ideas out and its just what I was looking for. Many thanks. Now just to fit it into the rest of my code!

Comment: If you think it solves your question I'd be happy to collect the 15 points when you accept the answer ;-) (click the check mark next to the answer)